# how to find related code with debug view hierarchy in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

in Android, we can use uiautomatorviewer/hierarchyviewer to find a view's Id quickly, and with the Id, we can find the related code.

My question is: in iOS, how can I find the related code via debug view hierarchy?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality in Xcode view debugger, however you can use accessibilityLabel to distinguish views in view debugger.

Comment: how to use accessibilityLabel?

Comment: You can set `accessibilityLabel` for any view in code or storyboard. Then you can user right pane in Xcode to see property list in view debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode's inspector allows you to jump to the definition of a view's class.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but for those default UI controls, such as "UIButton", how can I  find the related code that creating/using it?

Comment: You may be able to navigate to its superview (which may be a custom view created by you) and jump to its definition. Otherwise I don't know of a way to accomplish what you're looking for in Xcode.